# How to store data of not logged in users per session?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables, repository-pattern

I have a MVC4 application using Entity Framework 4 that makes use of the repository pattern. Once users are logged in they can do CRUD operations on the database layer and all information is persisted and linked to a specific user. Now I also want to make this functionality available to users who are not logged in so they can try the application. Once they decide to subscribe I want to persist the data they created in their try-out just as for logged in users in the database.

The setup of the application is that the Entity Framework Database context is abstracted behind an `IContext`. This means another implementation of IContext can be used. I am using Autofac as the DI-container. <sub>(If you feel like you need more information on the setup, all code can be found [here](https://github.com/erooijak/zaaikalender/tree/master/Zk)).</sub>

I am looking for a good way to implement the try-out functionality. What I thought about is:

1. Using an "in-memory" database per user, but I think this might take up way too much memory once too many users exist.
2. Another idea is to store the data on the client (JavaScript) and save all information once registering, but this seems like a big rewrite is needed and all C# logic needs to be translated to JavaScript and maintained together (once C# changes, the JavaScript has to change).
3. Saving the data in the database for a random `UserId` specific to the session, but once the user logs off remove all data related to the 'UserId'.

Perhaps there are better ways. I hope that if you have a good idea for the implementation of a try-out functionality you would be willing to share it with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use another Database? If yes, you can create another database to be 'playable' because this database is not for actual users. If starts to take to much memory can be rolled back. And if a user will want to register, you can move his data in actual database.

Comment: I just went with the third option for the app I'm working on and i think its a good option beause it adds not much overhead.

Comment: @adricadar, yes I can use another database! Then use a different Context (with another connection string) for non-logged in users and have another implementation of the services and logic which depend on the logged in user? :-) Sounds like a way to go. Thanks.

Comment: And @martinoss, That's also an option. Just overwrite is with an actual user later somehow? Can you elaborate on your setup? Thanks.

Comment: In my database design, each member can have multiple identities attached (from different OAuth providers), including a temporary user identity. I can match them using a client generated id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, **create another database** to be 'playable' because this database is not for actual users. And if starts to take to much memory can be rolled back with no risks. When a user will want to register, you can move his data from this database to the production database.

**Note:** You don't need to use a different context, or to implement another services. You can use a new instance of the context, but with a different connection string.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain how I can use a different instance of the context / different connection string for the context depending on if the user is logged in or not? And when the user registers the data needs to be copied from one to the other. I found [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137853/Cloning-the-Entity-object-and-all-related-children) which explains how to do that, so that is possible. Only problem is using the other connection string. Thanks.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers Because the user will be authentificated only when he uses the production database, you can check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and based on this you decide the context, if you use your custom log in system you can store in `Session` that user is logged in or not. If user must be authentificated no matter of what context is using, you can store in `Session` that user must use a context or another and when he try to register/log in he will use the *production context*. Don't try to add if/else in your actions except register or log in make context switch in Ctor or Factory.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the try out user registration very simple (just name and password and/or email if I want to send more information later) and then delete the users that not complete the full registration process after some amount of time

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I would scare off a lot of potential users by not having the try out. So not doing it is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest path forward is the third option. Create a temporary user record in the database for non logged in users. if you use cookies to recognize returning users, it will work seamlessly when these users return. Have some differentiator in the database record so that you can occasionally clean out temporary users.